# RadioButton invalid double

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to have 5 RadioButtons, and all of them aredescribed with text in XML file. And I want them to hold `double` value, different for each button.
And user has to input one number and then select one of the five options avalible in RadioButtons, then press on regular Button and that button will do the calculation (multiply entered number with double number holded by RadioButton).

I get force close error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "Sjedeći (Malo ili bez aktivnosti, pretežno sjedeći posao)"
```

This is my java file:

```
package hr.app.liftme.liftmehr;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class KalkulatoriTDEE extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText unesiteBMR;
    RadioGroup radioGrupa;
    RadioButton radioBtn1, radioBtn2, radioBtn3, radioBtn4, radioBtn5;
    Button btnIzracunajTDEE;
    TextView textRezultatTDEE;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kalkulatori_tdee);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Intent intent = getIntent();


        unesiteBMR = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUnesiteBMR);
        radioGrupa = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGrupa);
        radioBtn1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioBtn1);
        radioBtn2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioBtn2);
        radioBtn3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioBtn3);
        radioBtn4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioBtn4);
        radioBtn5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioBtn5);
        btnIzracunajTDEE = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIzracunajTDEE);
        textRezultatTDEE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textRezultatTDEE);

        btnIzracunajTDEE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                double prviButton = Double.parseDouble(radioBtn1.getText().toString());
                double drugiButton = Double.parseDouble(radioBtn2.getText().toString());
                double treciButton = Double.parseDouble(radioBtn3.getText().toString());
                double cetvrtiButton = Double.parseDouble(radioBtn4.getText().toString());
                double petiButton = Double.parseDouble(radioBtn5.getText().toString());



                prviButton = 1.2;
                drugiButton = 1.375;
                treciButton = 1.55;
                cetvrtiButton = 1.725;
                petiButton = 1.9;

                double rezultat = 0;
                double input = 0;

                if (radioBtn1.isChecked()){
                    rezultat = input * prviButton;
                } else if(radioBtn2.isChecked()){
                    rezultat = input * drugiButton;
                } else if (radioBtn3.isChecked()){
                    rezultat = input * treciButton;
                } else if (radioBtn4.isChecked()) {
                    rezultat = input * cetvrtiButton;
                } else if (radioBtn5.isChecked()) {
                    rezultat = input * petiButton;
                }
                textRezultatTDEE.setText(Double.toString(rezultat));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And this is XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="hr.app.liftme.liftmehr.KalkulatoriTDEE"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_kalkulatori_tdee">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout22"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Unesite svoj BMR:"
            android:id="@+id/textView115" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editUnesiteBMR" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout22"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout23"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/radioGrupa">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sjedeći (Malo ili bez aktivnosti, pretežno sjedeći posao)"
                android:id="@+id/radioBtn1"/>


            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Laka aktivnosti (Lake vježbe/sport 1-3 dana sedmično)"
                android:id="@+id/radioBtn2"/>



            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Umjeren (Umjerene vježbe/sport 3-5 dana sedmično)"
                android:id="@+id/radioBtn3"/>


            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Teške aktivnosti (Teže vježbe/sport 6-7 dana sedmično)"
                android:id="@+id/radioBtn4"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ekstremne aktivnosti (Teške dnevne vježbe/sport i fizički posao 2 x dnevno)"
                android:id="@+id/radioBtn5"/>



        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout23">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Izračunaj"
            android:id="@+id/btnIzracunajTDEE"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="#424242"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Vaš TDEE je:"
            android:id="@+id/textView116"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/textRezultatTDEE"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following, which attempts to convert your radiobuttons texts  into `double`, and causes the crash :

```
double prviButton = Double.parseDouble(radioBtn1.getText().toString());
double drugiButton = Double.parseDouble(radioBtn2.getText().toString());
double treciButton = Double.parseDouble(radioBtn3.getText().toString());
double cetvrtiButton = Double.parseDouble(radioBtn4.getText().toString());
double petiButton = Double.parseDouble(radioBtn5.getText().toString());
```

Instead, just initialize your `double` fields with the values they should have, like this :

```
double prviButton = 1.2;
double drugiButton = 1.375;
double treciButton = 1.55;
double cetvrtiButton = 1.725;
double petiButton = 1.9;
```

Comment: Yea, just did that minute after I posted question. Button now works, but result is always 0, seems like it does not take user input value

Comment: Sure enough, you initialize the input : "_double input = 0;_", but you never change this value anywhere in your code, so the result of your multiplication will always be 0.

Comment: Hmm, if double input = 0 then result is always 0, if double input = 100, multiplication works but I want user to input a number and then that number to be multiplied

Comment: I guess so, you probably want to do that instead : "double input = Double.parseDouble(unesiteBMR.getText().toString());"  (or use whatever widget field you meant to use for user input) .

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

```
btnIzracunajTDEE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

                double input = Double.parseDouble(unesiteBMR.getText().toString());
               double prviButton = 1.2;
                double drugiButton = 1.375;
                double treciButton = 1.55;
                double cetvrtiButton = 1.725;
                double petiButton = 1.9;

                double rezultat = 0;


                if (radioBtn1.isChecked()){
                    rezultat = input * prviButton;
                } else if(radioBtn2.isChecked()){
                    rezultat = input * drugiButton;
                } else if (radioBtn3.isChecked()){
                    rezultat = input * treciButton;
                } else if (radioBtn4.isChecked()) {
                    rezultat = input * cetvrtiButton;
                } else if (radioBtn5.isChecked()) {
                    rezultat = input * petiButton;
                }
                textRezultatTDEE.setText(Double.toString(rezultat));
            }
        });

    }
}
```